# add a multi-step form to WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I got a multi step form on codepen

```
<a>https://codepen.io/atakan/full/gqbIz/</a>
```

but it doesn't managed on WordPress.I added html, css and JavaScript on contact form 7 and added the external jQuery by a plugin but it didn't work.
So really want to know is their any other plugin to add this type of multi step form.

Otherwise how to add this form to wordpress site. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are finding plugin solution, both Gravity Form and Ninja Form supports multi-step form.

[Gravity Form - Multi-page form demo](http://demo.gravityforms.com/multi-page-form-sample/)
[Ninja Form - Multi-part form add-on](https://ninjaforms.com/extensions/multi-part-forms/)

Comment: I added a Gravity Form but can you help me to find out shortcode from gravity form.